# Something similar to "plepentry envoy"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, latin

Long time ago I heard a word that to the best of my recollection is "plepentry envoy"

I have googled a few variants, but "pleopentry envoy", "pelepentry envoy" etc.  but nothing similar is coming up. This is a long shot, but the word was suppose to mean something like an envoy that was dispatched by a royal with full mandate without requiring to approve their decisions by the King himself as they would have been acting on behalf of the King ( Of course if later King find out or decided that they did not act as he would then off with their heads).

Anyone has any hints on how to chase up this word?

Comment: It need not be *envoy* alone. Plenipotentiary can be applied in other ways as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're looking for "plenipotentiary", meaning "full power" from the Latin.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plenipotentiary

Answer (score 3):

Regarding "hints on how to chase up this word", try a reverse dictionary.  For example, entering *[envoy with full mandate](http://www.onelook.com/?w=%2a&loc=revfp2&clue=envoy+with+full+mandate)* at [onelook](http://www.onelook.com/reverse-dictionary.shtml) shows *[plenipotentiary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plenipotentiary)* as the first entry, while entering just *[envoy](http://www.onelook.com/?w=%2a&loc=revfp2&clue=envoy)* gives *minister plenipotentiary* as the seventh entry.

A plenipotentiary is a "person invested with full power, especially as the diplomatic agent of a sovereign state, (originally) charged with handling a certain matter", per wiktionary.

Answer (score 2):

As Christi says. It's still in use. The full designation of a British ambassador is 'Her Britannic Majesty's Ambassador Extraordinary and Plenipotentiary'.